# Method breaking after while without return

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to build an api to talk to network assets, so I created a class that implements the connection and conversation with these assets, but when debugging, when the breakpoint hits the `while` a second time, the console fires as if it were requesting user interaction.

```
using Provisioning.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Provisioning.Contexts
{
    public class TL1Context : IDisposable, ITL1Context
    {
        private static readonly TcpClient _tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        public TL1Context(string addr, int port)
        {

            _tcpClient.Connect(addr, port);

            if (!_tcpClient.Connected)
                throw new TimeoutException("Not has possible connect to TL1 server.");

            Login();
        }

        public TL1Context()
        {
            _tcpClient.Connect("10.1.5.12", 3337);

            if (!_tcpClient.Connected)
                throw new TimeoutException("Not has possible connect to TL1 server.");

            Login();
        }
        private void Login()
        {
            var strin = $"LOGIN:::CTAG::UN=GEPON,PWD=GEPON;" +
                        $"LOGIN:::C000::UN=GEPON,PWD=GEPON;" +
                        $"SHAKEHAND:::CTAG::;";

            var returnedMessage = this.SendMessage(strin);
        }

        private string SendMessage(string Message)
        {
            try
            {
                var stream = _tcpClient.GetStream();

                byte[] messageSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Message);

                stream.Write(messageSent);

                var messageReceived = new byte[1024];
                string textedMessage = string.Empty;
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int numBytesRead;
                    while ((numBytesRead = stream.Read(messageReceived, 0, messageReceived.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        ms.Write(messageReceived, 0, numBytesRead);
                        textedMessage += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("NOT EXECUTE THIS");
                    return textedMessage;
                }


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        public void Logout()
        {
            var strin = $"LOGOUT:::CTAG::;";
            this.SendMessage(strin);

        }

        public IList<ONUAvailable> GetOnusUnauthorizated(List<OLT> olts)
        {
            // TODO            
            foreach (var olt in olts)
            {
                var strin = $"LST-UNREGONU::OLTID={olt.IpAddress.ToString()}:CTAG::;" +
                    $"LST-UNREGONU::OLTID={olt.IpAddress.ToString()}:C000::;";
                var response = this.SendMessage(strin);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Logout();
            _tcpClient.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Console App for debugging

```
using Provisioning.Contexts;
using Provisioning.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var tl1 = new TL1Context();

                    // NOT EXECUTE THIS
                    Console.WriteLine(tl1._tcpClient.Connected);
                    tl1.GetOnusUnauthorizated(new List<OLT>() {
                    new OLT() { IpAddress = new System.Net.IPAddress(new byte[] {192, 168, 99, 2 })
                    }
                    });


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

In both cases, the follows lines of TL1Context never are executed

```
Console.WriteLine("NOT EXECUTE THIS");
return textedMessage;
```

@Edit: included console app for debugging

@Edit: I realized that NetworkStream, property of TcpClient is with some exceptions, could this be the cause?

[image]

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: The catch not received anything.

Comment: Which catch? Have you debugged the code?

Comment: Also why static tcpclient?

Comment: Yes, I debugged, the while loop is executed once and then the entire application gets kicked, the debugging ends and nothing is returned to the Controller. Static will keep only one instance.

Comment: So what will happen when you dispose of one instance of `TL1Context` and try to create another one?

Comment: I suggest you test the context in isolation to narrow the possible causes of the problem.

Comment: Just noticed action definition `async Task<ActionResult<string>>` but nothing is awaited in the action. That is not how to use async Task

Comment: I created a console app to debug better as you suggested, I got the same problem when code  `while ((numBytesRead = stream.Read (messageReceived, 0, messageReceived.Length))> 0)` is executed, It executes the instructions once, then returns the application to the foreground waiting for something to execute.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `.Dispose()` (or, failing that, a `using() {}`). Connection leaks will cause all sorts of weird behavior.

Comment: Also, you're second `Console.WriteLine(tl1._tcpClient.Connected);` is invalid, since at that point `tl1` (and `tl1._tcpClient`) have been `Dispose`d of.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling Synchronous call from an async method
try this in your controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Test()
{
    try
    {
        //var tl1 = new TL1Context();
        //OnuAuthService.Test();
        var tl1 = Task.Run(() => new TL1Context());
        var TL1ContextOutput = await tl1;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return BadRequest(e);
        throw;
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Not working, same with the method as sync not working. Thks for the response.